# Asp.net MVC site deployed to Microsoft Azure Web Sites throws error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** Update 3.
I have **ASP.NET MVC 4** website. Target framework: `.NET Framework 4.5`. The site have its own database. The site works locally and interacts with database (`(LocalDb)\v11.0`).

Then I deployed the site to **Azure Web Sites** through VS using **Publish** button. Web App was published successfully. But I'm unable to open it in browser. I receive the following error in browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> *The system cannot find the file specified*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

Stack trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1000
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +800
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +741
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +451
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +943
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +139
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +367
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +129
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +47
   WebMatrix.Data.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext() +67
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +183
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args) +98
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +19
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(IDatabase db, String tableName) +54
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded() +50
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables) +71
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +51
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables) +55
   OnlineAuction.MvcApplication.SetSecurityOptions() +60
   OnlineAuction.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +51

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +477
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +657
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +96
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

---

Here is my DB connection string in `Web.config`:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=OnlineAuctionDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlineAuctionDb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I uploaded entire `Web.config` file to [*DropBox*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0hfstd3hngizln/Web.config?dl=0)

---

Is it a problem with database or not? I have published the whole site by using **Publish** button in VS. But may be database is not attached to the cloud web app? I'm not sure. If the problem is in missing database how can I publish database associated with the website so they work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely that the website can't find or communicate with the database.  There are several ways to do this, but you will need to figure out how you want your database to be hosted - it looks like you're using SQL, so your options are:

1. SQL Express/LocalDB on the instance that your website is running on
2. Azure SQL DB (which will be hosted in azure and accessible by your website)
3. SQL Server hosted in VMs in Azure
4. Another SQL database hosted elsewhere (on premises maybe) and can be accessed by a hybrid connection

I'd recommend option 2, since it gives you a managed solution out of the box that can scale with your app, but is network addressable, so multiple instances of your web app can share it, it's backed up automatically, etc. etc.

Perhaps share some more information on what you've got already or what you have in mind you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have created SQL database in Azure. Tried to connect my Web App and SQL it failed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699106/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-site-with-existing-database-to-microsoft-azure-web-app

Comment: That other link has a completely different failure - it connects but the schema's not been created

Comment: For me it works when I add some configuration in the app service's app settings. Just set the name of connection string the same name with the connection string saved in your web app's web.config file. For example, your app uses connection string named "DefaultConnectionString", you should put this also to the connection string in app service together with the reconfigured connection string